# Sorting map where value is an object with multiple values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I initialized the map like:

```
var map = new Map();
```

when i do `console.log(map)`, i get:

```
testCreateBadAppointmentRequest: 
   { name: 'testCreateBadAppointmentRequest',
     time: 0.02926,
     status: 'Passed' },
  testAppointmentRequestAPI: 
   { name: 'testAppointmentRequestAPI',
     time: 0.051030000000000006,
     status: 'Passed' },
```

I want to sort this map on the time attribute of the value.
How do i do that in nodejs?
Is there a ready sort function to do so?

Comment: What does "sort this map" mean?

Comment: Do you mean convert it to an array and then sort? `Map` doesn't need sort.

Comment: @FisNaN Yes, I mean that

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert the `Map` to an `Array` first then use the built-in `sort` and provide a callback:

```
const sorted = Array.from(map).sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.time < b.time) return -1;
    if (a.time > b.time) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) order is determined by insertion order.

> It should be noted that a Map which is a map of an object, especially a dictionary of dictionaries, will only map to the object's insertion order—which is random and not ordered.

Convert map to array with [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on the map iterable. Then sort the array:

```js
const map = new Map()
map.set('testCreateBadAppointmentRequest', { name: 'testCreateBadAppointmentRequest', time: 0.02926, status: 'Passed' });
map.set('testAppointmentRequestAPI', { name: 'testAppointmentRequestAPI', time: 0.051030000000000006,  status: 'Passed' });

// convert map to array
console.log('array', [...map.entries()]);
const array = Array.from(map);

// sort (inverse sort to change your current sort)
array.sort((x, y) => y[1].time - x[1].time);
console.log('sorted', array);

// create new map with objects pairs in the desired order:
const timeSortedMap = new Map(array);
console.log('sorted map', [...timeSortedMap]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new Map object, since a Map object iterates its elements in insertion order.

```js
    const inputMap = new Map(
      [
        ['testCreateBadAppointmentRequest',
          {
            name: 'testCreateBadAppointmentRequest',
            time: 0.02926,
            status: 'Passed'
          }
        ],
        ['testAppointmentRequestAPI',
          {
            name: 'testAppointmentRequestAPI',
            time: 0.051030000000000006,
            status: 'Passed'
          },
        ],
        ['another',
          {
            name: 'name',
            time: 0.0001,
            status: 'Passed'
          },
        ]
      ]);

    const sortedMap = new Map([...inputMap.entries()].sort((entryA, entryB) => entryB[1].time - entryA[1].time));
for (const value of sortedMap.values()) {
  console.log(value)
}
```